# Beginners Problem with ReactNative FlatList

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm pretty new to react native and have an issue that my data is not showing up in my view.
I can retrieve it from my server and save it in the data array.
When I want to go through it and create a flatlist it doesn't show up and I don't know why.
The console.log output shows that I have data in my array and also displayList is true at that point in time. Any help why this happens ?

```
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title="Retrieve Data" onPress={fetchData} />
      <Text>before</Text>
      {console.log(
        `Size of Data: ${data.length} and displayList: ${displayList}`
      ) &&
        displayList &&
        data &&
        data.map((item, i) => (
          <FlatList
            data={data}
            renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item["name"].Value[0]}</Text>}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item}
          />
        ))}
      <Text>after</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By mapping over the flat list you are creating a new list for each item of data which I doubt it what you want to do.

The internals of render item have the map function in for you.
I think what you're looking for is...

```
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title="Retrieve Data" onPress={fetchData} />
        <Text>before</Text>
            <FlatList
                data={data}
                renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item["name"].Value[0]}</Text>}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
            />
        ))}
        <Text>after</Text>
        <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
);
```

If you want to render something else if theres no data then you can use the `ListEmptyComponent` prop on the flat list.

Im also not sure what your `data` array looks like. But this may also be an issue. If this doesn't work please update your question with the full component and data structure.

Answer (score 0):

try this, Don't have to iterate through map, the item is already containing the object for respective index.

```html
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title="Retrieve Data" onPress={fetchData} />
      <Text>before</Text>
      {data.lenght()>0?        <FlatList
            data={data}
            renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item["name"].Value[0]}</Text>}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item}
          />:<Text>No DATA FOUND<Text>}
      <Text>after</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
```